# What happens when a multiple file transfer is interrupted?

Tags: linux, mv

I used `mv` to move some files from `/source_dir/` to `/target_dir/`, which looked like: `mv /source_dir/*some_regex* /target_dir/`.

One of the files which started to move, `file1`, is now in both `target_dir` and `source_dir`.

`target_dir/file1` weighs considerably less than `source_dir/file1`.
My question is: Is `source_dir/file1` broken? Is it unaffected (in which case I can delete `target_dir/file1` and rerun the mv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file is removed after copying is finished. Therefore, source file stays unaffected until the operation is completed.

If moving on the same filesystem, a different mechanism is used, where the data stays in place.